# Hide/show chart placeholders in Excel 2016 (Office 365)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm trying to write a macro to hide/show chart placeholders in Excel 2016 (Office 365).  I have been using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.DisplayDrawingObjects = xlPlaceholders
```

which used to work in old Excel, but now nothing happens.  `= xlHide` and `= xlAll` work, but I don't want to hide the charts as I want to see their location in the worksheets.  How should I be doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "I want to see their location in the worksheets"?

Comment: My quick research led to no result. Next I would look at the environment, items like Application.ScreenUpdating or which is the ActiveSheet or the effect of hidden sheets in the workbook or, in fact, if there is a countermanding command (or one with such an effect) following the one you query. Try stepping through the code using F8 while watching the screen.

Comment: By "I want to see their location" I meant that using xlHide (which works) effectively makes the chart disappear from the spreadsheet, whereas xlPlaceholders (which no longer works in Office 365 Excel)) should show an empty border box in lieu of the full chart.

Comment: Tried adding "Sheets("mySheetName").Activate" first with no effect.  Stepping through code doesn't reveal anything as using xlPlaceholders doesn't work.  Note, as mentioned, xlHide/xlAll toggling works, just not xlPlaceholders.